# Daily average function that creates figures out of excel data

Tags: excel, matlab, function, plot

I need to make a function which creates plot figures out of excel data.
The data I have are hourly data, and the plots I need are plots of the hourly data, daily average en monthly average. I wrote some code but unfortunately it isn't working

Code:

```
function makegraph

[a,b] = xlsread('C:\..matlabdata.xlsx'); %read data

lengte = size(b);

datumstring = b(2:end,:); 

formatin = 'mm/dd/yyyy' ; 

Datums= datenum(datumstring(:,1),formatin); 

[~,j] = size(a); 

timeplusphysicalflow = [datums, a(:,4)]; 

nrDates = size(datums,1);
subplot(3,1,1),  plot(datums,a(1:nrDates,4)); %plot voor de hourlyflow


datetick('x','mm/yy')

u = unique(datums); %bekijkt wat de unieke data zijn


[YU,MU,DU] = datevec(u); 
CurrentYear = YU(1); 
CurrentMonth = MU(1); 
CurrentDay = DU(1); 

nrMonth = unique(strcat(num2str(YU) ,num2str(MU)));  
nrDays = unique(strcat(num2str(YU) ,num2str(MU), num2str(DU)));

AverageMonths = zeros(length(nrMonth),1);

for k=1:length(nrMonth) 

index = (MU == CurrentMonth   & YU == CurrentYear);
AverageMonth(k) = mean(timeplusphysicalflow(index,2));  

AverageMonths(k) = [AverageMonth(k)];




end

AverageDays = zeros(length(nrDays),1);

for o=1:length(nrDays) 

index = (MU == CurrentMonth   & YU == CurrentYear & DU == CurrentDay);
AverageDay(o) = mean(timeplusphysicalflow(index,2));  

AverageDays(o) = [AverageDay(o)];


end


subplot(3,1,2),  plot(unique(strcat(num2str(YU),num2str(MU)),AverageMonths)); 
subplot(3,1,3),  plot(unique(strcat(num2str(YU),num2str(MU), num2str(DU)))); 

end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider adding a tag for whatever language it is you're using.

Comment: Would help if you could tell what language that is. This is obviously not VBA.

Comment: Sorry it's matlab code